# How to wrap all HTML elements in a DIV depending on total height of those HTML elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a functionality where I want to show elements in a div of height 1000px. There are multiple records coming from DB but height of each element is not fixed. When height of records displayed cross 1000px, they should be wrapped in one DIV. Next records should be wrapped in another DIV till the height of those elements total to 1000px. Record should not get broken in between because of separate DIVs.

For example:

```
<div class="record">..</div>
<div class="record">.....</div>
<div class="record">...</div>
<div class="record">....</div>
<div class="record">..</div>
```

If total height of first 3 .record totals to 940px & height of first 4 .record totals to 1100px, jQuery should convert the code to:

```
<div class="page>
    <div class="record">..</div>
    <div class="record">.....</div>
    <div class="record">...</div>
</div>
<div class="page>
    <div class="record">....</div>
    <div class="record">..</div>
</div>
```

I am spending lot of time on it but could not make it work. :(

Comment: what if height equals to 941?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : Elements should be wrapped in .page div until they total upto 1000 px. When total height cross 1000px, last element should be wrapped in next .page div.

Comment: So you are appending those `.records` dynamically.? Show the static html where the data from DB getting appended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2w9hk616/4/)

But to explain it in details:

#### Some declarations:

```
var $records = $('.record'), // get all records
    total = 0, // current height of all elements
    group = 0, // iterator for groups
    limit = 200; // your limit in px for each .page (put your 1000 here)
```

#### First loop:

```
$records.each(function() {
    var $record = $(this);

    total += $record.outerHeight(true); // sum height of all records

    // when total height overflow your limit 
    // reset total and set next group index
    if (total > limit) {
        total = $record.outerHeight(true);
        group++;
    }

    // assign group index to each record
    $record.attr('data-group', group);
});
```

#### And second loop:

```
// iterate on all groups and using jQuery .wrappAll()
// wrap all records from one group to .page element
for (var i = 0; i <= group; i++) {
    $('[data-group="' + i + '"]').wrapAll('<div class="page"></div>')
}
```

More about [jQuery .wrappAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

Look out for `.outerHeight(true)` and all CSS `margins/paddings/borders` etc, because in this solution they will be counted in into example (I don't know if it's ok for You)

Comment: Great, nice to help :)

Comment: Why are we using `total = $record.outerHeight(true);` inside that `if`? I didn't understand the reason.

Comment: To reset current total height. When You exceed total height (when total is bigger than your limit) I set height of current element as total to start again like from first element. For example you have 4 elements: 70px 20px 30px 20px and limit as 100px. So 1st iteration: group: 0, total: 70px, 2nd iteration: group 0, total 90px, 3rd iteration: group 1, total 30px (becasuse 90px + 30px > 100px), 4th iteration: group 1, total 50px